# CSS: Using shape-outside property on svg in image tag

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm having a bit of a problem getting the

> shape-outside:

property to work on my page.  I'm calling it through a class on an SVG file and I have the text wrapped in paragraph tags.

```
<div class="content_section_comfortable spacer_top gallery_content_container">

<img src="http://optiqvision.x10host.com/Photos/svg/Red_Swatch.svg" / class="dynamite_color_swatch">

<p>
   text text blahblahblah
</p>
```

I created a class for the IMG tag rather than

> gallery_content_container img{ stuff: blah; }

because I'll have other photos in there that I don't want the effect to apply to.

The CSS for the img class is

```
.dynamite_color_swatch {
  width: 8em;
  height: 11em;
  /*display: block;*/
  float: left;
  shape-outside: polygon(67.3190000000em 0.9660000000em, 20.0270000000em 30.0750000000em, 1.0200000000em 98.6410000000em, 20.0270000000em 167.2050000000em, 67.3190000000em 196.3140000000em, 114.6110000000em 167.2050000000em, 133.6190000000em 98.6410000000em, 114.6110000000em 30.0760000000em, 67.3190000000em 0.9660000000em, 67.3190000000em 0.9660000000em);
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(67.3190000000em 0.9660000000em, 20.0270000000em 30.0750000000em, 1.0200000000em 98.6410000000em, 20.0270000000em 167.2050000000em, 67.3190000000em 196.3140000000em, 114.6110000000em 167.2050000000em, 133.6190000000em 98.6410000000em, 114.6110000000em 30.0760000000em, 67.3190000000em 0.9660000000em, 67.3190000000em 0.9660000000em);
}
```

I used an online generator to get the polygon code from an SVG file I made so I didn't know if something was wrong with it.  I tried switching up and using a png file, still nothing.  I switched the IMG tag to a DIV and linked the picture as a background and set the size to "contain" and "cover", didn't work.  I toggled

> display: block;

on and off with each thing I tried, still nothing.  I noticed I had a margin set to my p tags and commented that out of the CSS figuring there's a good chance that could be causing it to not work, but that had no effect either.

Here's a fiddle of the situation https://jsfiddle.net/Optiq/6ab9g34k/5/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Offhand your `shape-outside` coordinates/points seem very large in proportion to the image. `196em` !?

Comment: oh wow I didn't even realize that lol.  thanks, I've never utilized this before and I thought the converter would jsut do it to scale, I had to adjust the "divide by" thing to get it to scale.

Comment: Actually, I'd just use an ellipse here - https://jsfiddle.net/qsnjhrom/